# Icon is still showing in launcher after removing the application

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite

I have uninstalled an app but its icon is still showing in the Launcher. I have restarted the mac but still the icon is there.

S.P: the application has a Question mark on the icon and nothing is happening when I am clicking on it.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it was an App Store app, then just click & hold on any icon in the Launchpad, until they start to shake.
App Store apps will have an X in the top left corner to delete.

For a non App Store app, you will need to use Terminal & erase it from the database...

`sqlite3 $(sudo find /private/var/folders -name com.apple.dock.launchpad)/db/db "DELETE FROM apps WHERE title='APP_NAME_CASE_SENSITIVE';" && killall Dock`

Both of these solutions require admin privileges.